# running a .sh file in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sh, git-bash

I have a .sh file in my machine containing "kill -9 $()" this line. I am unable to run this file. When I run that file it appears git bash and suddenly disappeared. Please help me to find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your .sh (shell script) file seems to run fine with git bash for Windows actually.

The real question is: what are you trying to run?

If `kill -9 $()` is the only command inside that script, it does exactly what it is supposed to do: nothing.

`Kill -9` followed by a PID (Process ID, an integer number), kills the task with that PID.

`$()` is a "command substitution". If you put another command inside round brackets, the output of that command will be used as the value to pass.

So, let's say:

```
kill -9 $(pgrep -x php)
```

The command above will terminate all the running tasks named exactly "php" (if any).

I believe you should put some useful stuff inside round brackets to see any real effect, supposed that killing a task is what we can call "see" an effect.

Bye.